# « Stop au cirque royal »

Tags: prépositions

I noticed that the recent British headline 'Stop this Royal Circus' has been translated in the French media as '*Stop au cirque royal*'. I take it that this French 'Stop' is imperative. But is it normally followed by the preposition '*à*'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construction is deceptive to the reader of English. The verb that is extracted from the English "to stop" is not "stop" in French, but "stopper".

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stopper)) **stopper**

An imperative would not be used in French.

- <s>Stoppe ce cirque royal</s>

Instead an infinitive with the force of an imperative is what would be used.

- Stopper ce cirque royal.

In "Stop à ce cirque royal", "stop" is a noun.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stop)) **stop** *Interj. et subst. masc.*

It is an ellipsis as in "Non à ce cirque royal".

- Nous disons non à ce cirque royal. — Il faut dire non à ce cirque royal. —  etc. — Untel a dit non à ce cirque royal. — etc.
- Il faut mettre un stop à ce cirque royal. — Nous disons stop à ce cirque royal. — etc.

[image]

[dit stop à, plenty of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dit%20stop%20%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)